# Анимация ширины StackPanel XAML

Tags: xaml, анимация, windows-phone-8.1

Есть скрытый StackPanel, имитирующий нечто вроде выпадающего списка. Он должен появляться аннимируя свою прозрачность от 0 до 1, ширину от 100 до 264 и высоту от 30 до автоматической. Пишу код:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContractSelect_Panel"
            Width="100"
            Height="30"
            Opacity="0">

    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowModal">

            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContractSelect_Panel"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="1" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>

            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContractSelect_Panel"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                             To="264" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>

            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContractSelect_Panel"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                             To="Auto" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
</StackPanel>
```

Проблема в том, что прозрачность анимируется нормально, а вот ширина как была 100 так и остается. Значение "Auto" для параметра Height вообще выдает исключение XamlParseException.

**UPD**. Код немного исправлен, в частности StackPanel обернут в Border для границы и скругления углов. Анимация перенесена на Border. Grid - это подложка под всплывающее окно. Теперь он выглядит так:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ModalLayout"
          Tapped="ModalLayout_Tapped"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.RowSpan="3"
          Background="#00FFFFFF"
          Visibility="Collapsed">

        <Border x:Name="ContractSelect_Border"
                Background="#FFF4F4F4"
                Opacity="0"
                Width="100"
                MinHeight="30"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0 75 0 0"
                CornerRadius="8"
                BorderBrush="#C9CED3"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="ShowModal">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContractSelect_Border"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="1" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContractSelect_Border"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                    To="264" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
                </Storyboard>

                <Storyboard x:Name="CloseModal">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContractSelect_Border"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="0" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Border.Resources>

            <StackPanel x:Name="ContractSelect_Panel"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: А `Auto` и не должно работать. `Auto` по сути есть NaN, а как вы предлагаете анимировать double-величину к NaN?

Comment: В таком случае не могли бы вы подсказать, как сделать правильно, если заранее не известно значение высоты? 
Может как-то From="0" To="{this.ActualHeight}"? К сожалению пока плохо дается синтаксис расширений.

Comment: Ну, если у вас реальные границы 100/264, то почему `<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContractSelect_Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=OuterGrid}" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>`, где `OuterGrid` — охватывающий элемент.

Comment: Сделал как Вы сказали, однако высота, как и ширина, упорно отказывается анимироваться. Есть шанс что это проблема в эмуляторе, и на реальном девайсе все будет работать как задумано?

Comment: Хм. Я пробовал не на мобильном устройстве, а в WPF. Насчёт ограничений мобильного устройства не уверен. :-( Попробуйте, и гляньте, какие сообщения уходят в лог.

Comment: Есть возможность показать пример рабочего кода с анимацией ширины StackPanel? Сверюсь со своим.

Comment: Сейчас кину, момент.

Comment: Вот: http://pastebin.com/GhTYWJhH, срабатывает по клику в зелёный прямоугольник.

Comment: Странно, этот пример нормально отрабатывает в WPF, но под Win Phone 8.1 ширина и высота как и прежде не отрабатывают. Я удивлен в том, что есть разница.
Может действительно эмулятор глючит...

Comment: @VladD Можно немного оффтоповый вопрос? Мне сильно помог Ваш пример `{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=OuterGrid}`, очень удобно, много где использую, спасибо. Но можно ли как-то использовать простые вычисления, например взять половину от ActualHeight? Как ни пробую - компилятор ругается

Comment: Ну, можно хитростями заставить поделить пополам (в Grid выделить две колонки размера `*`, например). Но это скорее всего слишком окольный путь, проще сделать конвертер: http://pastebin.com/wRTAGfxE. Используется так: `{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Arena, Converter={StaticResource Scaler}, ConverterParameter={src:Double 0.5}}`.

Comment: Спасибо. Получается проще в бэккоде ширину посчитать и назначить. Думал может есть какое-то простое выражение.

Comment: Или так :) Обычно тенденция такая, что весь layout management выносят в XAML, так что подход с конвертером не так уж и плох. Но если вы вычисляете координаты в коде, уж проще это делать там. Преимущество связки Binding+конвертер в том, что когда исходная ширина изменяется, привязанная к ней, даже через конвертер, автоматически подхватывает изменения. Ловить в коде изменения ширины обычно не очень удобно.

Comment: Ну в принципе звучит вполне логично) Спасибо Вам, Вы меня уже не в первый раз просвещаете =)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Задавайте вопросы, наш сайт специально для этого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением к анимации `EnableDependentAnimation="True"`.

Answer (score 5):

У вас `Storyboard.TargetName="ContractSelect_Panel"` отличается от `<StackPanel x:Name="Select_Panel"`

Comment: Ой, ошибка закралась в процессе перепечатывания, сама разработка на другой машине. На самом деле в самом коде имена идентичны, сейчас поправлю вопрос.

Comment: @Олег Не уверен получится или нет, но попробуйте найти высоту родителя `StackPanel`

Comment: Не получилось. Какой задан элементу начальный Height, с тем и показывается

Comment: выложите код всей страницы, если ли вокруг stackpanel `grid` или еще чтото?

Comment: Код всей страницы очень длинный, выложил ту часть, где подложка на весь экран и собственно само модальное окно в нем. Сам код претерпел некоторые изменения, в частности StackPanel теперь обернут в Border и вся анимация на нем теперь, проблема сохраняется. Прозрачность работает как надо, ширина и высота не хотят